# How can I customize the "Fatal Error" screen?

Tags: error, custom-templates, error-page

I would like to change the language on the "Fatal Error" screen that users occasionally encounter by adding some text specific to my organization. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure CiviCRM to use a customized "fatal error" screen by following the steps below. You may want to include specific site administrator contact information or other problem resolution instructions on the screen, as well as "theme" it for a more professional or consistent look.

1. Save a copy of `civicrm/templates/CRM/error.tpl`
2. Edit the text and layout of this file as desired. You can add site administrator contact info, site logos, etc. as needed.
3. Login (with Admin CiviCRM rights) and navigate to Administer » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling
4. Replace the default value (`CRM/error.tpl`) with the relative path (from `civicrm/templates`) and name of your new file.
5. Save your changes.

You can also configure CiviCRM to use a custom error handler by referencing a custom PHP function in **Administer » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling**

You might also be interested in the [CiviCRM Error Handler](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-error-handler) extension which sends a detailed email to an administrator every time CiviCRM encounters a fatal error.

*This content was migrated here from this [wiki page](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Custom+Error+Screens+and+Error+Handlers) as part of the 2017 wiki content migration project*